# Unable to process string with \n in .html.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a string which is usually like

```
@error = "Error - No data \n Error - Incorrect id \n Error - Msg not relayed \n";
```

In my **show.html.erb** file:

I have something like '<%= @error %>`

But when printed on screen, it comes as a single line, and not in 3 separate lines?

Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
@error = "Error - No data <br/> Error - Incorrect id <br/> Error - Msg not relayed <br/>"
```

And in your view:

```
<%= @error.html_safe %>
```